# Looping a dictionary and printing the values?

Tags: python

I'm asking here again 'cause I don't know how to do this...
I have this code:

```
prices={'banana':4, 'apple':2, 'orange':1.5, 'pear':3}
stock={'banana':6, 'apple':0, 'orange':32, 'pear':15}

for e in prices and stock:
    print e
    print "price: " + str(e)
    print "stock: " + str(e)
```

and in

```
print "price: " + str(e)
print "stock: " + str(e)
```

I want to loop and print the value, e.g "1.5" in price and "32" in stock, but it prints the key, "orange" and I don't know how to loop and print the value of all the dictionary, can you please help me?

Comment: `for e in prices and stock:` will only loop over the keys in `stock` due to the nature of the `and` operator. If you want to loop over *both* you'll have to do that differently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over just *one* of the dictionaries, and use mapping access to print the values:

```
for e in prices:
    print e
    print "price:", prices[e]
    print "stock:", stock[e]
```

The above, however, will raise a `KeyError` if there are keys in `prices` that are not present in the `stock` dictionary.

To ensure that the keys exist in *both* dictionaries, you can use [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to get a set intersection between the two dictionary key sets:

```
for e in prices.viewkeys() & stock:
    print e
    print "price:", prices[e]
    print "stock:", stock[e]
```

This will loop over *only* those keys that are present in both dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as you said! The page keep saying that it don't works but it works perfectly, I think I will just ignore the page! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys are always the same between `prices` and `stock` you can simply do this:

```
for key in prices:
   print key
   print "price: " + prices[key]
   print "stock: " + stock[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

`prices and stocks` resolves either to `prices` or to `stocks`, but never to the concatenation of both.

This is how it works: Python does layz evaluation of `X and Y`. First it looks at `X` and if it is falsy (i.e. e.g. `False` or `[]` or `None`), then the expressions resolves to `X`. Only if `X` is not falsy (i.e. e.g. `True` or `[1,2]` or `42`) it returns `Y`.

Some examples:

```
>>> 2 and 3
3
>>> [] and 3
[]
>>> 2 and 'hello'
'hello'
>>> [] and 'hello'
[]
>>> [] and None
[]
>>> 42 and []
[]
```